# How to import and run ivy+ant project in eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, ivy, eclipse-juno

this is my first use of ivy+ant and after building the project from command line, i want to import it into eclipse juno.
the project folder (trunk) contains the following folders/files:

- build
- dist
- src
- WebContent
- build.properties
- build.xml
- ivy.settings.xml
- ivy.xml

i tried to import the trunk folder that contains the above files/folder using **import existing  projects** into workspace, but i get the error that **no projects found**.

pleases advise how to import this project.

**UPDATE**: i tried to configure the project for eclipse before importing using the following command:

```
ant eclipse-default
```

but i get the following error:

**Target "eclipse-default" does not exist in the project**

**UPDATE 2:**

i was able to import the project in eclipse as follows

**File > New > Other > Java Project From Existing Ant Buildfile**

but when trying to run the project on server, i can't find run on server in the run options, please advise.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this:

1. Install IvyDE from http://www.apache.org/dist/ant/ivyde/updatesite (ref: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/download.cgi)
2. IvyDE may not recognize your setting and properties file. At Window -> Preference -> Ivy -> Settings, check reload the setting on demand, add Ivy setting path `ivysettings.xml` or your Ivy setting file, Property files `build.properties` or your Ant properties file.
3. Add new Java project you want to work on, point the path to your project.
4. At the new project wizard, Libraries tab -> Add Library -> IvyDE Managed Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can not import a project of you do not have the eclipse project information in your code.
Either create a new eclipse project from existing source.
Or a new java project from ant buildfile (your update 2).

For running need configuration of server (hard to know what youneed there), you may need to create new server (preference/server/run time environnement) (or from view server, right click "new")